# How to view XULRunner logs?

Tags: debugging, logging, xulrunner

I have an XULRunner-based application that is crashing, for reasons I do not understand. To help pin down the problem, I would like to view any and all logs produced by XULRunner. To that end:

1. Does XULRunner produce any sort of error logs?
2. If so, where exactly are they located?

Answer (score 1):

While there are [instructions on turning on some logging for XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/XULRunner/Debugging_XULRunner_applications), I would suggest building [with `--enable-debug`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Configuring_Build_Options) and getting a stack trace and/or viewing the console output from that build.